# Meteor: How to write a publish-function containing the username

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish, publish-subscribe

Note: Whole code can be found here:

https://github.com/Julian-Th/crowducate-platform/

Currently, all items from an array are displayed in one single list instead of a separate list tag:

I have a pub function, which works perfectly:

```
Meteor.publish('editableCourses', function () {
    return Courses.find({"canEditCourse": { $in: [ this.userId ] } });
});
```

However, I want to use the username instead. So I tried the following with no result:

```
Meteor.publish('editableCourses', function () {
    return Courses.find({"canEditCourse": { $in: [ this.user.username ] } });
});
```

My JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : "P5JFAfrxaNpApvZWW",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-12-30T17:38:47.506Z"),
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$lLskLjO6W2eoA06Ws5sC/upq6Stbh1eTbgTAN3wa39RCD8x7GU1ZS"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [ 
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2015-12-30T17:38:47.605Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "g2rye+mwrNNsjL3mHtxT+sYXgj3OGoEZsGRMyVEI47I="
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "username" : "User1",
    "emails" : [ 
        {
            "address" : "user1@test.com",
            "verified" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for your help, appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items of the `Courses` Collection is what you are publishing.

So when you query with `Courses.find({"canEditCourse": { $in: [ this.userId ] } });` the `canEditCourse` field is what you are trying to match to a `userId` (it literally means find all Courses where the `canEditCourse` array contains the userId.)

I don't see why you would want to use username here instead though. What does that get you?

If you do want to do this, then you need to have the `canEditCourse` field be an array of `username` and not `userId`. 
That means you need to change the logic where the Courses are created or edited and where this field is being filled.

Not sure it is worth the trouble. If what you want is look Courses up by username, then look up the User by username, get his/her userId and lookup the Courses by userId.

```
Meteor.publish('editableCourses', function (username) {
    var myUser = Meteor.users.findOne({'username': username});
    return Courses.find({"canEditCourse": { $in: [ myUser._id ] } });
});
```

Comment: Especially if usernames can ever be changed. User `_id`s are immutable.

Comment: @MichelFloyd exactly: i was going to point out that `username` must be unique, but they should also be immutable or you will end up with incoherent data lookup in the future

Comment: I mark your answer as solved as you and @MichelFloyd make me aware of the poor design. I'm going to ask a new question, which shed is going to shed light to this issue from a different perspective. It's just a bit complicated to explain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538544/meteor-how-to-subscribe-show-usernames-when-this-userid-is-published