# Meteor: How to subscribe/show usernames when this.userId is published

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, subscription

Note: Whole sourcecode can be found here:

https://github.com/Julian-Th/crowducate-platform/

I have the following pub functions:

```
Meteor.publish('editableCourses', function () {
    return Courses.find({"canEditCourse": { $in: [ this.userId ] } });
});

Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
    if (this.userId) {
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
            {fields: {'realname': 1, 'username': 1, 'gender': 1, 'language': 1, 'biography': 1 }})
    }
});

Meteor.publish("allUsernamesExceptCurrent", function () {
  // Get current user
  var currentUserId = this.userId;

  // Get all users except current,
  // only get username field
  var users = Meteor.users.find(
    {_id: {$ne: currentUserId}},
    {fields: {username: 1}}
  );

  return users;
});
```

Here's the template:

```
<template name="myTeachingCourses">
  <button class="btn btn-primary js-create-course"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create a Course</button>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
      <ul class="thumbnails list-unstyled">
          {{#each courses}}
          {{>courseCard}}
          {{/each}}
      </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

The helper with subscription:

```
Template.myTeachingCourses.helpers({
    'courses': function(){
      return Courses.find();
    }
});    

Template.myTeachingCourses.created = function () {
      // Get reference to template instance
      var instance = this;

      // Subscribe to all published courses
      instance.subscribe("editableCourses");
    };
```

The problem: The template doesn't render the created courses. A course creator can't see his own courses or add other collaborators. I wonder if the reason might be, because canEditCourse is now an array with usernames and not with IDs.

```
My JSON for Courses:
{
    "_id" : "hRX8YABpubfZ4mps8",
    "title" : "Course Title here",
    "coverImageId" : "Qojwbi2hcP2KqsHEA",
    "author" : "Name",
    "keywords" : [ 
        "test", 
        "meteor"
    ],
    "published" : "true",
    "about" : "Testing",
    "canEditCourse" : [ 
        "User1"
    ],
    "createdById" : "zBn6vtufK2DgrHkxG",
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2015-12-29T21:42:46.936Z")
}
```

Via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534557/meteor-how-to-write-a-publish-function-containing-the-username/34534983#34534983) question I found out that storing usernames in the array is not a good idea for now obvious reasons. In the beginning, I actually stored IDs instead of usernames but then changed it because to use the username for autocomplete with typeahead and rendering the IDs of all collaborators is not good thing to do. What is the best way to fix it? In other words, how is it possible to render all created courses.

Comment: I would suggest you get MeteorToys package (free version is fine). use CTRL + M to see your data in the browser. It makes life a lot easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

So, as you answered yourself, your Courses collection field `canEditCourse` has an array of `usernames`, not `userId`, so the query will not return anything.

Comment: how about changing the helper, to this: 

`Template.myTeachingCourses.helpers({
    'courses': function() {
   var myUser = Meteor.user().username;
   return Courses.find({"canEditCourse": { $in: [ myUser ] } });
    }
});`

This seems to work. Is it ok to do that?

Comment: Sure. This was my answer to your other question, but you still have the problem of the possible mutability of the username: if a user change his/her username, your username lookup will return the new username, and unless you update all Courses to replace usernames in the array whenever a user change username, the username there will be the old one. That means the new username will not be found in the Course object and the Course will no show up in the query results.

Comment: What you should really do if you want to allow search by username, is do the opposite: store objects you want to lookup by their ID  (user ID for users), and lookup user ID from username. Because user ID are immutable, if the username changes it will not affect your lookup: when you search for ID for a username, it will always find the same ID for a given user, even if the username was changed.

Comment: If you want to search by username as you mentioned at some point, you can have a list of user objects, and display the username as the visual cue, but use the ID for the lookup. An html input list, drop down or such widget allow you to have a display string and a value: you display the username but use the value (user ID in this case) as the selection.

Comment: "store objects you want to lookup by their ID (user ID for users), and lookup user ID from username. Because user ID are immutable, if the username changes it will not affect your lookup:" <-- exactly! how can I do that?(considering pub/sub)